# Spork RingNotFound Runtime Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, spork

I got this error when i try to exec Spork

```
c:\Sites\new\app1>bundle exec spork
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Using RSpec, Rails
  -- Rinda Ring Server listening for connections...

  -- Starting to fill pool...
     Wait until at least one slave is provided before running tests...
  ** CTRL+BREAK to stop Spork and kill all ruby slave processes **
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
   -- build slave 1...
   -- build slave 2...
Preloading Rails environment
Preloading Rails environment
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
For a better pry experience, please use ansicon: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/
For a better pry experience, please use ansicon: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine/rinda_ring_finger_patch.rb:18:in `lookup_ring_any': RingNotFound (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rinda/ring.rb:109:in `finger'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rinda/ring.rb:118:in `primary'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rinda/ring.rb:245:in `provide'
        from magazine_slave_provider.rb:26:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine/rinda_ring_finger_patch.rb:18:in `lookup_ring_any': RingNotFound (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rinda/ring.rb:109:in `finger'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rinda/ring.rb:118:in `primary'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rinda/ring.rb:245:in `provide'
```

My Gemfile is this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'

end


require 'rbconfig'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/i

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

My Ruby version is :

```
c:\Sites\new\app1>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

and Rails version is :

```
c:\Sites\new\app1>rails -v
Rails 4.0.2
```

I also found  this two conversation about a similar error on GitHub
https://github.com/guard/guard-spork/pull/91

https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/pull/214

but i couldn't find a solution to my problem

Someone Can Help me?
Thank you
Stefano